# What a graph should look like with a diameter at least 5 times the average shortest path length?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to find what a graph should look like with a diameter at least 5 times the average shortest path length. I understand that it must be a compete graph with a long tail, cause with longer tail diameter will grow faster than the average shortest path length. But I don't know how to find exact number of nodes of that graph. How many nodes there must be in complete graph and how many in tail? Could I define those numbers using formulas of graph diameter and average shortest path length?

By experiments and iterations, I found that complete graph with 100 nodes and tail with 11 nodes has diameter 12 and  average shortest path length 2.097, so it is 5 times larger, but how to find it using math?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to find one example of such a graph, your idea works : take a huge complete graph (mean path length is $1$), add small tail (it shouldn't change the mean path length because the tail vertex are rare), and it should work.

The exact value of the average path length on such a model can be computed by hand by a case disjunction (both ends are in the complete part, or one end in the complete and the other in the tail, or both in the tail), but I'm not sure I want to do it. But it's interesting to see how this works asymptotically. If you have $n$ nodes in the "complete" part and $k$ in the tail, you'll have approximately (up to corrective terms, the expected path length in a class is just an approximate value) :

$\frac 1 {(n+k)^2} \left [ n^2*1 + 2nk*\frac k 2 + k^2*\frac k 3 \right ]$

To have something close to 1, you need that $nk^2 + k^3 \ll (n+k)^2$ so $k \ll \sqrt n$.

If you want even more "efficiency" (small complete graph compared to the ratio diameter/path length), I'd suggest having two tails instead of one : you should have an average path length about twice as small with the same diameter.
It's the same as placing the complete graph in the middle of the path, so that the central term in the sum becomes $2nk*\frac k 4$.

Anyway, those are not the only graphs that will give you such properties.
An Erdös-Renyi graph with fixed average degree $\ge 3$ will have an average path length in $\log(n)$, and you could use that instead of the complete part of your graph and still have small ratios.

Comment: In your example, you took $k \approx \sqrt n$, which indeed made the central term approximately equal to $n^2$ and the total value approximately equal to 2.

Comment: As OP just asked for the ratio to be at least $5$ you can ignore the first two terms in the sum and say you want $\frac 13k^3 \gt 5(n+k)^2$ and solve for $k$ given $n$.  For $n=3$  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k%5E3%2F3%3D5%28k%2B3%29%5E2) gets that $k=20$ is enough

Comment: This value isn't the ratio, it's the average path length $\bar d$. The ratio value is $\frac k {\bar d}$, so to have a big ratio you actually want the value I wrote to be small, as close to 1 as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the minimum complete graph $K_i$ that with two $j$-node tails would produce a ratio of diameter to average shortest path, $r>5$.

[image]

I found the average shortest path in five parts:

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{Part of graph} & \text{#paths} & \text{av. length}\\ \hline
\text{Within }K_i & i(i-1)/2 & 1   \\
\text{Tails to base} & 2j  &  (j+1)/2  \\
\text{Tails to other }K_i & 2j(i-1) &  (j+1)/2 + 1  \\
\text{Tails to self} & j(j-1)  & (j+1)/3   \\
\text{Tail to tail} & j^2 &  j+2  \\ \hline
\end{array}

Of course there was a minimum smallest $K_i$ for any given $j>2$. Slightly unexpectedly this was itself minimum at $j=5,6$ (I thought it would be higher before the length of the tails became significant):

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
j & \min i \\ \hline
3 & 52  \\
4 & 39  \\
5 & 36  \\
6 & 36  \\
7 & 37  \\
8 & 38  \\
9 & 40  \\ \hline
\end{array}